# Is there any tool or API to infer AS-path between any 2 arbitrary Autonomous System?

Tags: routing, asymmetric-routing

Dear all experts out there,
Is there any tool or API to infer AS-path between any 2 arbitrary Autonomous System?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Anything outside of your AS is outside of your control, and it is subject to change at any time; it could be different from one second to the next (you hope that's not the case, but how another AS administrator runs his AS is nothing you can control). As your `asymmetric-routing` tag suggests, the routing may be asymmetric, and there is nothing you can do about it. You may have some leverage with the directly connected AS as a business realationship, but anything beyond that is really unknowable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decent `traceroute` implementations (eg: Linux, OSX) will provide the `-a` flag to enable AS Path Resolution eg:

```
bendale@lojack> traceroute -a 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1   [AS1] 10.0.0.254 (10.0.0.254)  5.374 ms  2.632 ms  4.363 ms
2   [AS0] 10.0.254.10 (10.0.254.10)  1.159 ms  1.106 ms  1.040 ms
3   [AS0] 10.192.2.209 (10.192.2.209)  1.846 ms  1.732 ms  1.586 ms
4   [AS0] 10.192.2.221 (10.192.2.221)  1.815 ms  1.808 ms  1.680 ms
5   [AS0] 10.1.254.6 (10.1.254.6)  2.349 ms  2.237 ms  2.086 ms
6   [AS0] 10.1.254.1 (10.1.254.1)  1.803 ms  2.305 ms  1.690 ms
7   [AS9268] *.*.*.* (*.*.*.*)  3.658 ms  2.630 ms  2.403 ms
8   [AS9268] *.*.*.* (*.*.*.*)  2.649 ms  17.428 ms  2.789 ms
9   [AS9268] te3-0-0.pe1.400har.syd.core.overthewire.net.au (180.214.88.45)  14.679 ms  14.429 ms  14.608 ms
10  [AS56220] as15169.nsw.ix.asn.au (218.100.52.3)  14.700 ms  15.524 ms  14.633 ms
11  [AS15169] 216.239.40.223 (216.239.40.223)  14.669 ms
    [AS15169] 216.239.41.77 (216.239.41.77)  15.065 ms
    [AS15169] 216.239.40.233 (216.239.40.233)  15.303 ms
12  [AS15169] 209.85.251.53 (209.85.251.53)  16.045 ms
    [AS15169] 72.14.237.7 (72.14.237.7)  15.305 ms
    [AS15169] 216.239.41.17 (216.239.41.17)  15.773 ms
13  [AS15169] google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  15.932 ms  18.645 ms  15.831 ms
```

however, this will only give you an answer in one direction (from your local AS to the remote AS).  The return path could be (and often is) completely different.

Good network service providers will often offer Looking Glasses that you can use to examine their routing tables and/or run traceroute from for troubleshooting purposes, but unfortunately not all do.

The following resources may help:

- http://www.bgp4.as/looking-glasses - fairly comprehensive list of Looking Glasses around the world.  If you can't find one on the network you are troubleshooting, try to find one on an adjacent network.
- http://www.traceroute.org - online traceroute tool plenty of global coverage
- https://www.robtex.com/as - Search for an AS in the search box eg: "AS7474" and then click the first link that comes up.  Shows routing-policy, Peers, Customers, and a graph showing upstream connectivity

Comment: Dear Dale, Thank you for your informative answer. I tried to install the traceroute on my Ubuntu and run the command as you provided, but it seems like Traceroute does not have the "-a" syntax.

Comment: Confusingly, Ubuntu seems to require a capital A eg: traceroute -A 8.8.8.8